# MySQL query - get row with highest number filtered by another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data similar to this:

```
id  job_id  filename    status  revision    product
----------------------------------------------------------
1   1       1r0.jpg     P       0           Product 1
2   1       2r0.jpg     P       0           Product 2
3   1       3r0.jpg     P       0           Product 3
4   1       2r1.jpg     P       1           Product 2
```

I want to run an SQL query that returns the following:

```
id  job_id  filename    status  revision    product
----------------------------------------------------------
1   1       1r0.jpg     P       0           Product 1
3   1       3r0.jpg     P       0           Product 3
4   1       2r1.jpg     P       1           Product 2
```

i.e. if there's two rows with the same `product` name, I want to get the one with the highest `revision` number.

I've tried lots of queries using `groupby`, `max`, `distinct` to no avail. I've tried self-joins but cannot get the results I'm after.

For example, the query `SELECT *, MAX(revision) FROM artworks GROUP BY product` gives me data that looks fine at first glance but the row contains the data from the one with the lowest revision number, not the highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without `GROUP BY`, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM artworks a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM artworks aa
    WHERE a.product=aa.product AND a.revision < aa.revision
)
```

Comment: That's great, it's works exactly how I want it to. Thank you! So it's getting all the info, then doing a subquery to exclude anything with the same product name and lower revision number. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the same result without a sub-query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM artworks a
left join artworks b
on a.produc = b.produc
and a.revision < b.revision
where b.id is null;
```